# Understanding the partial derivative with respect to the weight matrix and bias

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, backpropagation, gradient-descent

Say we have the layer $X W + b = Y$.

1. I want to get $\frac{dL}{dW}$ and we assume I have $\frac{dL}{dY}$.
   So all I need is to find $\frac{dY}{dW}$. I know that it should be $X^T\frac{dL}{dY}$ but don't understand why. please explain.
2. I want to get $\frac{dL}{db}$ and we assume I have $\frac{dL}{dY}$.
   So all I need is to find $\frac{dY}{db}$. I know that it should be $\sum(\frac{dL}{dY})_i$ (I mean sum the rows) but I don't understand why. please explain.

Thanks :)

Comment: The TL;DR answer is that the partial derivative of $L$ with respect to the weights or bias is just an application of the chain rule. Maybe later I'll add a complete answer.

Comment: Yea I know that it is because of the chain rule. I’m looking for a concise clear proof.